# Stop Email from being sent Temporarily

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a number of Subscriptions on SQL Server Reporting Services that are automatically fired off on a certain day and time.  The only way I can think of stopping the subscription is to delete and then recreate it after.
 Is there any other way i could do this?

If i was to use this, would it work?

```
USE msdb
GO
EXECUTE dbo.sysmail_stop_sp
GO
```

Comment: One option is to change the 'End Date' of the reporting schedule to yesterday.  That will discontinue the report.  Once you are ready to resume running it, you can set the end date to a really far out date or leave it blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try pausing the shared schedule, as documented [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156369.aspx#bkmk_pause_schedule):

> **Pause a shared schedule**
>
> If a report or subscription runs from a shared schedule, you can pause
> the schedule to prevent processing. All report and subscription
> processing driven by the schedule is deferred until the schedule is
> resumed.
>
> - SharePoint mode: SharePoint Settings In Site settings, select Manage shared schedules. Select the schedule and click Pause selected
>   schedules.
> - Native mode: In report manager, click Site Settings. Select the schedule and then click Pause.